# Authentication token option is not there under install agents option

Tags: teamcity

I have tried to create agent so to achieve this task , I have clicked on build agent full.zip and configure it. However I am not finding the authentication token option to proceed further. Please assist.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just install, setup and start your agent with the correct TeamCity address

First it will fail, but in TeamCity you will see it as Unauthorized, click authorize, restart your agent and It works !

The server give the token to the agent once authorized, and the agent update its configuration accordingly